# I need migrate apps to use the latest Sheets API version V4

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get in a Google spreadsheet via the PHP API Client, but I am getting a 404->You need permission. I figure out that I use old turned-off sheets API version v3, what is couses this error 404->"You need permission"! Now I need to migrate my spreadsheet API from v3 to v4.

This is my gdata code, where I call class getspreadsheets(); :

```
 if(!$accessToken){
                
                $auth_url = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
                
                
            } else {
                
                try{
                    
                    $this->client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
                    $token = json_decode($accessToken);
            
                    if ($this->client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                        $this->client->refreshToken($token->refresh_token);
                        $tok = json_encode($this->client->getAccessToken());
                        $token = json_decode($tok);
                        $db->setQuery("Update #__breezingforms_addons_gdata set password = " . $db->quote($tok) . " Where form_id = " . intval($form_id));
                        $db->execute();
                    }
                    
                    $serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($token->access_token, $token->token_type);
                    ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);

                    $spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
                    $spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();
                    
                }catch(Exception $ee){
                    
                  //$accessToken = null;
                    //$auth_url = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
          $error=$ee->getMessage();
                              
                              }
            }

            if($spreadsheetFeed !== null){
                foreach($spreadsheetFeed As $sheet){
                    $gdata_spreadsheets[$sheet->getId()] = $sheet->getTitle();
                }
            }
            
            if($gdata->spreadsheet_id != '' && isset( $gdata_spreadsheets[$gdata->spreadsheet_id] ) && $spreadsheetFeed !== null){

                $spreadsheet = $spreadsheetFeed->getByTitle($gdata_spreadsheets[$gdata->spreadsheet_id]);
                $worksheetFeed = $spreadsheet->getWorksheets();
                
                foreach ( $worksheetFeed as $sheet ){
                    $gdata_worksheets[$sheet->getId()] = $sheet->getTitle();
                }
                
                if($gdata->worksheet_id != '' && isset( $gdata_worksheets[$gdata->worksheet_id] )){
                    
                    $worksheet = $worksheetFeed->getByTitle($gdata_worksheets[$gdata->worksheet_id]);
                    $cellFeed = $worksheet->getCellFeed();

                    foreach($cellFeed->getEntries() as $cellEntry) {
                        
                        $row = $cellEntry->getRow();
                        $col = $cellEntry->getColumn();
                        
                        if( $row > 1 ){
                            break;
                        }
                        
                        $gdata_columns[] = $cellFeed->getCell($row, $col)->getContent();
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        
        } catch(Exception $e){
            
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Sheets API v3 code for getting spreadsheets is:

```
namespace Google\Spreadsheet;
```

use SimpleXMLElement;

/**

- Spreadsheet Service.
- 
- @package    Google
- @subpackage Spreadsheet
- @author     Asim Liaquat asimlqt22@gmail.com
  */
  class SpreadsheetService
  {
  /**

  - Fetches a list of spreadhsheet spreadsheets from google drive.
  - 
  - @return \Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetFeed
    */
    public function getSpreadsheets()
    {
    return new SpreadsheetFeed(
    ServiceRequestFactory::getInstance()->get('feeds/spreadsheets/private/full')
    );
    }

  /**

  - Fetches a single spreadsheet from google drive by id if you decide
  - to store the id locally. This can help reduce api calls.
  - 
  - @param string $id the url of the spreadsheet
  - 
  - @return \Google\Spreadsheet\Spreadsheet
    */
    public function getSpreadsheetById($id)
    {
    return new Spreadsheet(
    new SimpleXMLElement(
    ServiceRequestFactory::getInstance()->get('feeds/spreadsheets/private/full/'. $id)
    )
    );
    }

  /**

  - Returns a list feed of the specified worksheet.
  - 
  - @see \Google\Spreadsheet\Worksheet::getWorksheetId()
  - 
  - @param string $worksheetId
  - 
  - @return \Google\Spreadsheet\ListFeed
    */
    public function getListFeed($worksheetId)
    {
    return new ListFeed(
    ServiceRequestFactory::getInstance()->get("feeds/list/{$worksheetId}/od6/private/full")
    );
    }

  /**

  - Returns a cell feed of the specified worksheet.
  - 
  - @see \Google\Spreadsheet\Worksheet::getWorksheetId()
  - 
  - @param string $worksheetId
  - 
  - @return \Google\Spreadsheet\CellFeed
    */
    public function getCellFeed($worksheetId)
    {
    return new CellFeed(
    ServiceRequestFactory::getInstance()->get("feeds/cells/{$worksheetId}/od6/private/full")
    );
    }
    }

How to make migrate on v4?
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`404 error code`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)  to indicate that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested. The resource can't be fetched due the deprecation of Sheets v3 API (Check the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration) for more references).

###### [Migrate your apps to use the latest Sheets API version—turning down v3 API by 2020](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/migrate-your-apps-use-latest-sheets-api)

> As part of the migration to the Sheets v4 API, which provides a better developer and user experience, we will be retiring the Sheets v3 API on March 3, 2020.

As you can see from the [PHP quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) of Sheets API, you must instantiate the class [`Google_Service_Sheets`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets.html) with a valid [`Google_Client`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets.html) as parameter:

###### `quickstart.php`

```php
// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client  = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$spreadsheetId = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms';
$range = 'Class Data!A2:E';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
```

If what you need is to list all the files that match the type sheets, you can use the Drive API client (adapted from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php#step_2_set_up_the_sample)):

###### `drive.php`

```php
$service_drive = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

$optParams = array(
  "q" => "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheets'"
);

$files = $service_drive->files->listFiles($optParams);
if (count($files->getFiles()) == 0) {
    print "No files found.\n";
} else {
    print "Files:\n";
    foreach ($files->getFiles() as $file) {
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
    }
}
```

Remember that you need to meet the **[prerequisites](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php#prerequisites)**:
[image: Prequesites]

and

```sh
composer require google/apiclient:^2.0
```

###### Documentation:

- [Drive API PHP](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/index.html)
- [Sheets API PHP](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/index.html)
- [PHP Google API Client](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-php-client/master/)

Comment: Hi @Emel, thank you very much for your detailed explanation! :)