# Spreadsheets error " String could not be parsed as XML"

Tags: google-sheets-api

When I try to get all titles of spreadsheets from Google drive, I got this message `The string could not be parsed as XML`:

```sh
ERROR ->  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in C:\....

ERROR-> SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): { in C:\....

ERROR-> SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ in C:\...
```

I try to connect on Gooogle drive, which I success, but I need to get the names of spreadsheets on Google drive, I previously use API v3 now I need to use V4.

this is code for call method getSpreadsheets();

```php
$serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($token->access_token, $token->token_type);
                        ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);

$spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
$spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();
```

This is the code of method getSpreadsheets:

```php
public function getSpreadsheets()
    {
        return new SpreadsheetFeed(
             

           ServiceRequestFactory::getInstance()->get('v4/spreadsheets/1u7WYzJOYMX7uH3AIM70yVLOaHBy8p_uifuJe_Saa2T4?fields=sheets.properties.title')
        
        
        );
    }
```

And this is SpreadsheetFeed class, where is error causes:

```php
namespace Google\Spreadsheet;

use ArrayIterator;
use SimpleXMLElement;

/**
 * Spreadsheet feed. 
 *
 * @package    Google
 * @subpackage Spreadsheet
 * @author     Asim Liaquat <asimlqt22@gmail.com>
 */
class SpreadsheetFeed extends ArrayIterator
{
    /**
     * The spreadsheet feed xml object
     * 
     * @var \SimpleXMLElement
     */
    protected $xml;

    /**
     * Initializes the the spreadsheet feed object
     * 
     * @param string $xml the raw xml string of a spreadsheet feed
     */
    public function __construct($xml)
    {
        $this->xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

        $spreadsheets = array();
        foreach ($this->xml->entry as $entry) {
            $spreadsheets[] = new Spreadsheet($entry);
        }
        parent::__construct($spreadsheets);
    }

    /**
     * Gets a spreadhseet from the feed by its title. i.e. the name of 
     * the spreadsheet in google drive. This method will return only the
     * first spreadsheet found with the specified title.
     * 
     * @param string $title
     * 
     * @return \Google\Spreadsheet\Spreadsheet|null
     */
    public function getByTitle($title)
    {
        foreach($this->xml->entry as $entry) {
            if($entry->title->__toString() == $title) {
                return new Spreadsheet($entry);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I try to find a solution how to pass this error!
Any Help, how to solve this error?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you specify where the `DefaultServiceRequest` class comes from ? If you are using this [library](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client), it seems that it is [not adapted](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client/issues/202#issuecomment-901093566) to use with Sheets API v4. As a recommendation you should rewrite your code using the [libraries](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/php/latest/index.html) provided by Google.

Comment: Hi Emel, Thank you for your feedback!
 Yes, I'm using that library, have you one example of how to do it? Do you have a library adapted to API v4? Many tnx

Comment: Hi Emel, I working on the adaptation library, I make some changes, and now I get stuck on an error where I'm described in the comment above!
DefaultServiceRequest class is okay, I didn't get an error from them, I adjusted them!

Comment: If you are trying to port the library to Sheets API v4, the best place to go is the library [repository](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client). If you are trying to perform another operation, such as getting all the spreadsheet titles, you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70083829/14271633) as a guide.

Comment: Hi @Emel, thank you, good man, I will try as you said, and I will let you know the result! Thank you very very much! :)

Comment: Hi @Emel, do you have an example of an [API spreadsheet library](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client) that has done a migration from V3 to V4? tnx :)

Comment: As I indicated in the other comment, the best thing to do is rewrite your code with the library provided by [Google](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback, I understand! :)

Comment: Hi @Emel, one more, thank you very much for your guidelines, I solved the problem, now everything works perfectly, I build a new app based on V4 spreadsheets API and, works! tnx :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you have the solution for the question you asked,  it would be great if you post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution for my app, migrate from v3 to v4 spreadsheets API:

```
$this->service_drive = new Google_Service_Drive($this->client);
                $optParams = array('q'=> 'mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"');
                $this->files = $this->service_drive->files->listFiles($optParams);
            }
                 // $this->service_drive = new Google_Service_Drive($this->client);

                  //$optParams = array('q'=> 'mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"');
                  //$this->files = $this->service_drive->files->listFiles($optParams);
                  //$gdata_spreadsheets=$this->files;//my test
                  if($this->files !==null){
                   if (count($this->files->getFiles()) == 0) {
                  $gdata_spreadsheets=array("No Spreadsheets");
                  } else {
                  foreach ($this->files->getFiles() as $file) {
                   $gdata_spreadsheets[$file->getId()]=$file->getName();
                  } 
                } 
        }
            //trenuto ispod code rjesavam
            if($gdata->spreadsheet_id != '' && isset( $gdata_spreadsheets[$gdata->spreadsheet_id] ) && $this->files !== null){

            $this->service = new Google_Service_Sheets($this->client);
            $this->response = $this->service->spreadsheets->get($gdata->spreadsheet_id);
            $this->sheets=$this->response->getSheets();
             
            // $spreadsheet = $this->service_drive($gdata_spreadsheets[$gdata->spreadsheet_id]);
              // $worksheetFeed = $spreadsheet->getWorksheets();
                
                foreach ( $this->sheets as $sheet ){
                   $gdata_worksheets[$sheet->properties->sheetId]= $sheet->properties->title;
                    //$gdata_worksheets[]=$this->sheets;
                }
               //$gdata_worksheets[]=$gdata->worksheet_id;
                if($gdata->worksheet_id != '' && isset( $gdata_worksheets[$gdata->worksheet_id] )){
                    $range = 'List 2!A1:Z';
                    $worksheet =  $this->service->spreadsheets_values->get($gdata->spreadsheet_id, $range);
                   $cellFeed = $worksheet->getValues();

                    foreach( $cellFeed  As $row) {
                       
                       //$row = $cellEntry->getRow();
                        //$col = $cellEntry;
                       // $gdata_worksheets=$this->service;
                        
                    
                       if( $row > 1 ){
                    $gdata_columns=$row;
                           break;
                            
                       }
                   }
                }
            }
            
       
        } catch(Exception $e){
            
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
```

This is one part of my code, where is described how to migrate from v3 to v4 spreadsheets API.